# How to render components with individual keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a dashboard and I want to use [React-Grid-Layout](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#demos) but I render the components only if they have been favorited. To use the gird layout each div needs a `key="a"` or `key="b"` depending on the layout defined each key needs to be different.

How can I go about giving each div an individual key? When it renders on-screen in its current form it renders two divs with the same cards in where I need it to render one div for each card.

```
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2, minW: 2, maxW: 4 },
    { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
  ];
```

render function

```
  const userHasFavorite = (data, favIds, layout) => {
  if (favIds && data) {
    const filteredData = data.filter((idsArr) =>
      favIds.split(",").includes(idsArr.id)
    );
    const keysMapped = layout.map((ids) => ids.i);
    console.log(keysMapped);
    return (
      <div key={keysMapped}>
        <PriceCard data={filteredData} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <p1>No Cards Have Been Faved</p1>;
  }
};
```

Grid Layout

```
 <GridLayout
          className="layout"
          layout={layout}
          cols={12}
          rowHeight={30}
          width={1200}
        >
          {isLoading ? (
            <LoadingCard />
          ) : (
            userHasFavorite(data, favoritedIds, layout)
          )}
  </GridLayout>
```

PRICE CARD

```
 return (
    <dl className="mt-5 ml-5 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          className="flex-row bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-purple-700  dark:bg-secondaryDark h-24 pt-2 px-4 pb-12 sm:pt-6 sm:px-6 shadow-2xl  rounded-lg overflow-hidden"
        >
          <div className="flex h-2 ">
            {/* TODO: ADD TRANSISITON   */}
            {cardFaved.some((cardFaved) => cardFaved.id === item.id) ? (
              <MinusSmIcon
                onClick={() => removeCardFavClick(item.id)}
                className="ml-auto h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer fill-current text-red-600 "
              />
            ) : (
              <PlusSmIcon
                onClick={() => handleCardFavClick(item.id)}
                className="ml-auto h-5 w-5  cursor-pointer  fill-current text-green-600 "
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <dt>
            <div className="absolute rounded-md p-3">
              <img className="h-6 w-6 mr-3" src={item.image} />
            </div>
            <p className="ml-16 text-sm pb-0  font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-white truncate">
              {item.name.toUpperCase()}
            </p>
          </dt>
          <dd className="ml-16 pb-7  flex items-baseline sm:pb-7">
            <p className="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              {formatDollar(item.current_price)}
            </p>
          </dd>
        </div>
      ))}
    </dl>
  );
};
```

export default PriceCard;

Error I'm having is the cards render 2 in one div

[image]

Error 2

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a unique key? Why not using the value of `i` in your layout object?

Comment: I want to do that just not sure how to iterate through and assign it to the div

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: What's about the docs example? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper, they show how to map data and assign as a key

Comment: Can you please the code involving the `<GridLayout>` since that's what you're asking about? How are you rendering the above component within the `<GridLayout>`?

Comment: Added some more info @MwamiTovi

Comment: Ok, I notice you mention using a `map()` but in the code there is a `filter()`, did you mean .filter? If not, can you also add the .map part?

Comment: @MwamiTovi updated the function the .filter is not relevant for the problem is basically gets some ids from redux for me

Comment: you need to map through your layout. Then you will be able to access the key ( i ) value for your divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from the [React-Grid-Layout official usage](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#usage),
 You need to `map()` directly within the `<GridLayout/>` component.

So here a good suggestion:

Within the GridLayout:

1. WITH map()

```js
<GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
  {isLoading 
    ? <LoadingCard />
    : layout.map(({ i }) => 
        <div key={i}>
          // change this from a typical function into a React component
          <UserHasFavorite data={data} favIds={favoritedIds} />
        </div>
   )}
</GridLayout>
```

2. WITHOUT map()

```
<GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
  {isLoading 
    ? <LoadingCard />
    : <React.Fragment> 
        <div key="a"><UserHasFavorite data={data} favIds={favoritedIds} /></div>
        <div key="b"><UserHasFavorite data={data} favIds={favoritedIds} /></div>
        <div key="c"><UserHasFavorite data={data} favIds={favoritedIds} /></div>
      </React.Fragment>}
</GridLayout>
```

Within the child component

```
const UserHasFavorite = (data, favIds) => {
  if (favIds && data) {
    const filteredData = data.filter((idsArr) =>
      favIds.split(",").includes(idsArr.id)
    );
    // <div> is moved up into the GridLayout
    return <PriceCard data={filteredData} />;
  } else {
    return <p1>No Cards Have Been Faved</p1>;
  }
};
```

**UPDATE:** To handle issue of rendering multiple "similar" cards

- Within the PriceCard, there is this...

```
return (
    <dl className="mt-5 ml-5 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          className="flex-row bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-purple-700  dark:bg-secondaryDark h-24 pt-2 px-4 pb-12 sm:pt-6 sm:px-6 shadow-2xl  rounded-lg overflow-hidden"
        >
        </div>
       )}
   </dl>
)
```

You are mapping to display all the cards in a row. So if you updated the `className="flex-column..."` those two cards should render in a Column but in one `<div>`.

And then if you do that, you have two options:

1. **Either** you delete the `<GridLayout/>` and render  directly like this...

```
 // <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
 return (
   isLoading 
     ? <LoadingCard />
     : <UserHasFavorite data={data} favIds={favoritedIds} />
 )
 // </GridLayout>
```

By removing the `<GridLayout/>` which is used for display, you will have just two cards rendered in a column (handled with `PriceCard` component).

2.**Or** render the `<PriceCard/>` directly to within the  like this...

```
// Parent component -> GridLayout
export const ParentComponent = props => {

  // I'm not sure where "data" and "favoritedIds" are coming from yet,
  // but we check like "data &&..." to ensure they are defined 
  // before we attempt to filter
   
  const filteredData = data && data.filter(
    (idsArr) => favoritedIds && favoritedIds.split(",").includes(idsArr.id)
  );

  return (
    <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
     {isLoading 
       ? <LoadingCard />
       : (!!data && !!filteredData)
         ?  <React.Fragment> 
              <div key="a"><PriceCard data={filteredData[0]} /></div>
              <div key="b"><PriceCard data={filteredData[1]} /></div>
              <div key="c"><PriceCard data={filteredData[2]} /></div>
            </React.Fragment>}
         : <p1>No Cards Have Been Faved</p1>
    </GridLayout>
  )
}

// Child component -> PriceCard
export const ChildComponent = props => {

 return (
    <dl className="mt-5 ml-5 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
      {data && /* don't map here -> we moved it to parent */
        <div className="flex-row bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-purple-700  dark:bg-secondaryDark h-24 pt-2 px-4 pb-12 sm:pt-6 sm:px-6 shadow-2xl  rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
          /* make necessary changes */
        </div>}
   </dl>
 )
}
```

Comment: Let me know... otherwsie, now you should not have the squash issue.

Comment: still having issues because if they are more than one priceCard favorited they will be multiple <PriceCards/ >  rendered so when they are it is rendering them all in the same div multiple times attached a picture above.  ERROR 2 picture

Comment: Does that happen if you work with `map()` and without `map()`?

Comment: thanks for all your help so far. if i remove the map it will render one dive with 2 <PriceCards/> in like the photo on IMAGE ERROR in the question

Comment: Here are my thoughts, you need to use the `map()` and then work on the css-styling to remove the squashing issue. The most important is that the cards are displayed... then you need to manage the css code.

Comment: @MeamiTovi Thanks. I fixed the styling and added a new photo on the Q showing the problem that two items render for each div instead of just one item in each div

Comment: That's good progress. So I'm not sure if I understand you right, you want one `<div>` to have "bitcoin" and the other to have "Cardano"? Is that what you want?

Comment: yeah that is correct @MwamiTovi

Comment: ok, let me refactor the answer... and let you know.

Comment: Can you add code for this component `<PriceCard data={filteredData} />`?

Comment: Added price card JSX @MwamiTovi

Answer (score 0):

From what I read I think that you need to iterate and assign it to the div. You can do something like this.

```
return (
 {filteredData.map(data => (
  <div key={data.i}>
    <PriceCard data={filteredData} />
  </div>
  )
);
```